# Login loop likely due to NVIDIA drivers with CUDA installed

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, login, cuda

A few days ago I ran a `sudo apt update` + `upgrade` on my Ubuntu 16.04. I had not done so for about 2 months. In the meantime, I had changed my graphics card from a GTX 1060 to a GTX 1070.

When today I tried to login, I discovered I had entered an annoying infinite login loop. This is the content of my `xsessions-errors` log:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  155 (NV-GLX)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  4 ()
  Resource id in failed request:  0x3d0
  Serial number of failed request:  46
  Current serial number in output stream:  46
openConnection: connect: No such file or directory
cannot connect to brltty at :0
[...]
```

Looking at the promising answers to this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop), I tried the following:

1. Check the ownership of `.Xauthority` belongs to me, and not `root` (it does belong to me)
2. Reconfigure `lightdm`
3. Reinstall `lightdm`
4. Check if my `/home/` is full (it's at 44% usage)

all unsuccessfully. Then I started believing my issue lies in a NVIDIA drivers update, as I read multiple sources on various websites explaining that was a common issue. It's worth adding I did not make any recent modification to `./profile` or similar, and never run the command `startx` in my life.

I found these potential solutions to my issue that revolve around NVIDIA drivers:

- installing `nvidia-current` drivers (older than latest supported by
  NVIDIA) as proposed [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/650253/748364);
- reinstalling NVIDIA drivers by running `nvidia-installer.sh` as proposed [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/alt.os.linux/N7IUgXKY50E);

My problem is that on my computer I spent tens of hours configuring CUDA, in a delicate balance with NVIDIA drivers, and various packages. For installing CUDA, I also had to install a specific Ubuntu kernel version (4.4).

Is there a chance that my CUDA environment will break if I touch the drivers? Is there actually anything else I could try to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To other people facing my same issue, I suggest trying the following:

```
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority-backup
```

which renames `.Xauthority` and forces the creation of a new one with the next login attempt. In case the problem laid there, then the login would work.

In my case, however, what actually worked was doing what I was afraid doing, which is reinstalling the NVIDIA drivers. For users of CUDA, the driver version that needs to be installed is defined by the [documentation](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html). In my case, as I had CUDA 9.1, it's at least driver version 390.46 (as per the moment I write this answer, of course).

I followed the instructions found on [this website](https://tecadmin.net/install-latest-nvidia-drivers-ubuntu/) to (re)install the drivers I needed. I actually also found this post from the [CUDA forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1030959/cuda-setup-and-installation/cuda-9-1-setup-and-nvidia-390-driver-not-found-on-ubuntu-16-04/post/5244741/#5244741), written by a moderator, explaining how on his experience using this source for the drivers may not always work, as they are not officially released by NVIDIA. In my case, it still worked and I therefore share it.

First, remove the installed NVIDIA drivers:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Add the repository for the graphics driver:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
```

Then install the correct version of the drivers (in my case, xxx = 390)

```
sudo apt install nvidia-xxx
```

And finally

```
reboot
```

The login problem should now be solved. In my case, the CUDA environment did not 
get affected and all my project still ran normally.

Comment: 390.48 is the current 390 driver from the standard repositories, no need for the graphics-drivers ppa.  The package name is nvidia-driver-390 (no longer in the form nvidia-xxx).

Comment: @ubfan1 Ah, thanks. So what command should I use to install it the proper way?

Comment: Clean out any previous nvidia packages and from Software and Updates, check the sources (I think universe is the one needed), and then under the Additional Drivers tab, let it scan and select the one that says "tested", or the latest one if a tested one is not available.

Comment: @ubfan1 Thank you. If you are willing to write an answer with the commands one would need to type I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: A search of this site already gives many correct answers to the Nvidia login loop problem, but you can accept your own answer since it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is try to reinstall the driver and reconfigure lightdm also. In the worst case you will need to install CUDA again but try reinstalling the driver first by downloading the installer from nvidia(the shell script).

> Is there a chance that my CUDA environment will break if I touch the drivers? Is there actually anything else I could try to fix the issue?

Not necessarily. As long as your drivers are in place. `nvcc` should function properly.

Comment: I eventually solved the problem yesterday night, and I indeed ended up reinstalling the drivers (actually went from version 387 to 390). Could you still elaborate on the 'shell script'? I followed [these](https://www.tecmint.com/install-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu/) instructions but read somewhere on CUDA's forum that this is not an official NVIDIA repository and saw myself it's actually quite behind in version.

Comment: sorry i meant the [run](https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/137276/en-us) file

Comment: If you can list the instructions such as `wget ...` and `run ...` I'll accept your answer. I am bound to console operations

Comment: wget [this](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/390.87/NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-390.87.run) and try to install by setting `quiet splash nomodeset`.